# How to extract data from SafeSubscriber?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, subscriber

I have to make an Angular application in which i **get data from the back-end and display it on the front-end**, but with some added hard-coded data.

My communication is between 2 files:

**client.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
import {catchError, map, Observable, of} from "rxjs";

const clientUrl = environment.apiUrl+'client';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

export class ClientService {

  public optional: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getText(): Observable<any> {
    console.log("it works!");
    return this.http.get(clientUrl+"/getText").pipe(map(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.optional = res.toString();
    }));
  }
}
```

and the second one:
**client.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ClientService} from "../client.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client',
  templateUrl: './client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client.component.css']
})
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

  public textResponse: any;
  constructor(public service: ClientService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  getText() {
    let text: any;
    this.textResponse = this.service.getText().subscribe();


    console.log(this.textResponse);
    text = this.textResponse + "This text is added from code.";
    console.log(text);
  }
}
```

When i call "*this.http.get(clientUrl+"/getText")*" I get a SafeSubscriber object, from which i managed to get the data displayed in  the console using the method "*.subscribe(...)*" with a "*console.log()*" inside of it. However, i did not find any method to extract the data out of this subscribe.

As the code above shows, i have tried to use pipe and map, but the local variable is returned as [Object object], and when i print it in the console i get either undefined, either nothing.

This is what my code currently displays:

```
it works! [client.service.ts:33]
SafeSubscriber {initialTeardown: undefined, closed: false, _parentage: null, _finalizers: Array(1), isStopped: false, …} [client.component.ts]
[object Object]This text is added from code. [client.component.ts]
{text: 'This text is read from a file.'} [client.service.ts]
```

I have also tried all the suggestions found in questions below:
[angular 2 how to return data from subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295854/angular-2-how-to-return-data-from-subscribe)
[Angular observable retrieve data using subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593725/angular-observable-retrieve-data-using-subscribe)

Does anyone know a method in which i could get the data out of the Subscribe?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `return` keyword when mapping the response, looking at the `console.log`, you need the `text` property

```js
getText(): Observable<any> {
    console.log("it works!");
    return this.http.get(clientUrl+"/getText").pipe(map(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.optional = res.toString(); 
        return res.text;
    }));
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because i can't call res.text. Only thisResponse.text which gives me "undefined".

Comment: Try removing the .text from the res variable, and return that.