# Don't fetch the right data format through http request

Tags: html, arrays, angular, http, object

I am working with Angular 8 for a web app. So I have a backend in which I have implemented some get http call. They all should return an array of objects.

My array of object has an interface of this type:

```
export interface MssInterface {
  operatingroom: number;
  sessionid: number;
  specialty: number;
  day: number;
}
```

I have created a mssService.ts to put all the GET together (in the environment.backendURL variable there is the first part of the address: http://localhost4200)

```
export class MssService {
  mssURL = environment.backendURL + "/api/mss";
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getS1(): Observable<MssInterface> {
    return this.http.get<MssInterface>(this.mssURL + '/uno');
  }
```

Then I have a component class in which I am subscribing to the mssService to fetch the data.  So i have written my home.component.ts like this:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  mssData: MssInterface;
  
  constructor(public mssService: MssService)

  mssToDisplayOne() {
      this.mssService.getS1().subscribe((MSS) => {
      this.mssData = MSS;
      console.log(this.mssData);
      });
  }
...
}
```

[Here the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kopQk.png)

Everything seems to work properly except that when I go to make a *ngFor inside the array of objects in the html code, it doesn’t return anything.

home.component.html :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mssData">
    
     <td *ngIf="item.sessionid %2==1"> {{item.operatingroom}} </td>
     <td *ngIf="item.sessionid %2==0"> {{item.operatingroom}} </td> 
     
   </tr>
```

I have tried to understand why nothing happend doing this thing :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mssData">
    
   <td>{{ item | json}}</td>
     
</tr>
```

And with this it displays my entire array of Objects.
[here the displayed object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMHgn.png)

So, what Am I doing wrong? Why it can't read inside my array of objects?

Comment: I have aready tried to do as answered in this other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593725/angular-observable-retrieve-data-using-subscribe)  but seems nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your result fetched from the API it includes an attribute called `session_id` but when it comes to the HTML template your `*ngIf` it includes the condition as `*ngIf="item.sessionid %2==1` which the sessionid is not equal to the data attribute being fetched from the API result. It has to be `session_id` try changing that attribute and check the results. Refer the below code attached:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mssData">
     <td> {{item.session_id%2==1 ? item.operatingroom : item.operatingroom}} </td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue! iI fixed it.

Comment: I cannot vote because I am still a beginner user. But I marked it as correct! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, if the your request does indeed return an array this works

```
mssData: MssInterface[];

constructor(public mssService: MssService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.mssService.getS1().subscribe((MSS: any) => {
        this.mssData = MSS;
        console.log(this.mssData);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have checked with a console.log(this.mssData) inside the mssToDisplayOne() function and it returns an array of object as I want. The mssToDisplayOne() is called in a <mat- select> togheter with the other function that doing the same things with arrays that have same structure but different data. That part seem to works, the consolo.log of each function works and the array are different on the base of the select that I choose. But with the ngFor doesn't work . Also the network response with 200 status so the call is done correctly.

Comment: Try declaring mssData as an array. Without full access to your code all I can do is guess, I tried running a similar project with all the information you've provided and it worked properly so my guess is that the error can be caused by other part of your code.

Comment: change mssData: MssInterface; to mssData: MssInterface[];

Comment: It's always the same, I've tried with: mssData:MssInterface[], mssData:any, and mssData:MssInterface.                      I'm going to be clearer if I can. The main problem is that the console.log(this.mssData) return something like this: [{full},{full},{full}...]. So when I try to read inside the object with the <tr *ngFor="let item of mssData"> is like if item is not the object wiith MssInterface, it's not readable. It seems there is another step to do but I don't know which is.  While doing the <td>{{item | json }}</td> it displays only the object inside my array without the [] bracket.

Comment: it displays only one object with <td>{{item | json }}</td> ? Have you tried to display <tr *ngFor="let item of mssData">
     <td> {{item.operatingroom}} </td>
</tr>
without the *ngIf to see if there's a problem with the sessionid or operatingroom parameters of the object?

Comment: Yes, I tried also without the ngIf condition and doesn't display anything

Comment: It seems like "item" is entirly the object inside the array, not only one object for times. Am I able to do another *ngFor to serach inside item? Because I think that item var is not defined in html and so can't be iterable.